# how to sort two array and add it to third one using textfield in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield

I am new in swift and I am facing problem to search one by one. I tried this code

```
let appln_id = "800016"

let result = (dict["listAarry"] as? [[String:Any]])?.filter({ ($0["appln_id"] as? String) == appln_id })
```

but I want to search it in textfield

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{


    if textField == txtSearch{
        let certificationId = txtSearch.text //"800016"

        let result = (searchdict["listAarry"] as? [[String:Any]])?.filter({ ($0["appln_id"] as? String) == certificationId })
    }

    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: So currently you have an dictionary with an array of dictionaries and you want only the values that  equal to the `appln_id` and `800016`?

Comment: @800016 yes but one by one like if I enter 8 in textfield then it will show all with 8 then same as 0 till 800016

Comment: So you want to see your search result in a list? lets say  6 results when typing "8" ?

Comment: Just add a target to your txtSearch textField for UIControlEvent `.editingChanged` with a selector to update your list

Comment: @Vollan Yes correct.

Comment: @LeoDabus Please check updated question with screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so stupid I just has to use contains instead of ==

```
txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AdmissionReportVC.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)

 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) { 
     var certificationId = String()
     certificationId =  txtSearch.text ?? ""
     print(certificationId)
     let result = (searchdict["listAarry"] as? [[String:Any]])?.filter({ 
     (($0["appln_id"] as? String)?.contains(certificationId) ?? false)})
     print("Result = ",result as Any
     SearchAny = result!
     tblView.reloadData()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are currently calling the delegate function of `shouldChangeCharactersIn` on the textField. However, what you want to do is call:

```
@objc func textFieldValueChanged(_ textField: UITextField)
```

Along with:

`searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldValueChanged), for: .editingChanged)`

in the valueChanged method you should do your filter but some minor editing and then put that into your `datasource` for `tableView` and run your `tableView.reloadData()`

```
let result = (va["listAarry"] as? [[String:Any]])?.filter({ (($0["appln_id"] as? String)?.contains("textInput") ?? false)})
```

Comment: I understand. But I want to do filter one by one my code gives result when only its equal to same.

Comment: How can I do same search with name as case sensitive?

Comment: @Muju Not sure which parameter you want to check but both your comparisons should be `.lowercased()`

Comment: Yes did this change it worked. But if user click on Capitalised button it again change to upercase Can we do something to prevent that?

Comment: @Muju You should still have the value in te dictionary Array? If you don't then you have to save it locally somewhere... Because you can't reverse a lowercased()

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let previousText:NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let updatedText = previousText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let result = dict.filter { (dict) -> Bool in
        if let app_id = dict["appln_id"] as? String {
            return app_id.contains(updatedText)
        }
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

result will hold valued on the basis of searched term.

Comment: what exactly you are getting in result array after adding above code?

Comment: Nothing its not going inside result.